# Create a 3D map with extruded polygons for use in ArcGIS Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, kml, 3d

I am working on a project which contains several choropleth maps (State and County level mostly).  In very simple terms, I would like to create 3D extrusions of the polygons based on an attribute.  So far I have worked in ArcGIS Pro and tried to publish these as a web scene but it seems that the extrusion part is not yet possible when publishing to ArcGIS Online.  I am open to working with KMLs or other formats.  In the end, I would like to be able to integrate whatever service or layer I create into the ArcGIS Javascript API but I am open to other platforms as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the extrusion you are setting in Pro that would go towards publishing a feature service in AGOL is not supported in the scene viewer.

You can do this in code with the JS API 4.0(currently in beta, final coming soon!).

Check out this blog to help you get started:
https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/01/25/3d-visualization-working-with-objects-paths-and-extrusion/

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for pointing me in that direction.